# Read empty line easily

Tags: c++, qt, fortran

If I want to read two numbers from data as follow:

```
1stLine "23"
2ndLine      *(emptyline)*
3rdLine "45"
```

In Fortran, it's quite easy cause u only need the READ,
say `READ(filename,*) Vari1,Vari2` then it will read "23"and "45" in. 
(because Fortran takes multiple successive "\n" as ONE)

But in Qt, with `readLine()` you have to read and use another code-line to judge whether it's empty, kind of annoying.

Is there a better way to get the `"23"` and `"45"` easily? I mean, with least codes, thanks.

Comment: In general, if there's something which is done in more than one line, but you want it done in one line, you write a function.

Comment: thanks. just finished the easy function.  What a lazy man I am, LOL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QFile file("your/file");
if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
    QMessageBox::information(0, "error", file.errorString());
}

QTextStream in(&file);

while(!in.contains("\n", Qt::CaseInsensitive)) {
    QString line = in.readLine();
    if(line != "\n"){
    ============================
    the jobs you want to be done
    ============================
    }  
}

file.close();
```

Comment: This code will not compile because QString does not define unary '!' operator. Maybe writing `if (line != "\n")` would be better?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I wrote to make READ like that in FORTRAN, and it works fine.

```
class FTextStream: public QTextStream
{
public:
    FTextStream(QFile *file);
    QString readLine2();
};

FTextStream::FTextStream(QFile *file)
    :QTextStream(file)
{}

QString FTextStream::readLine2()
{
    QString line;
    while(line.size() == 0){
        line = readLine();
    }
    return line;
}
```

However,it is not enough to only eliminate the empty line.
And further filtering details can be added to readLine2() or new ones.